# Sort an array which contains number and strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, ecmascript-6, numbers

I am trying to sort an array which contains strings, numbers, and numbers as strings (ex. '1','2'). I want to sort this array so that the sorted array contains numbers first and then strings that contain a number and then finally strings.

```
var arr = [9,5,'2','ab','3',-1 ] // to be sorted
arr.sort()
// arr = [-1, 5, 9, "2", "3","ab"] // expected result
//arr = [-1, "2", 5, 9, "ab"] // actual result
```

I have also tried

```
var number =[];
var char =[];
arr.forEach(a=>{
 if(typeof a == 'number') number.push(a);
 else char.push(a);
})
arr = (number.sort((a,b)=> a>b)).concat(char.sort((a,b)=> a>b))
// arr = [-1, 5, 9, "2", "3","ab"] // expected result
//  arr = [-1, 5, 9, "2", "ab", "3"]// actual result
```

Comment: Is there any reason for "2" and "3" to be after `9`? For that kind of sort, you can either sort twice or make a single unique complex sort.

Comment: @briosheje because they are strings. Looks like OP wants numbers first, then strings.

Comment: @briosheje "2" and "3" are after 9 because they are strings, So it goes [ints, integer_strings, non_numeric_strings] it seems

Comment: How should the "numbers as strings" be sorted? As nbers or as strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you have done most of the work in your second attempt.
All I have done here is used `Array.concat` to join the sorted results of `number` and `char` together.

```js
var arr = [9, 5, '2', 'ab', '3', -1] // to be sorted
var number = [];
var char = [];
arr.forEach(a => {
  if (typeof a == 'number') number.push(a);
  else char.push(a);
})


var sorted = number.sort().concat(char.sort());
console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: Hi , I have tried this "result = (number.sort((a,b)=> a>b)).concat(char.sort((a,b)=> a>b))". But i didn't get the expected output. Could you tell me how these two are different

Comment: @komal `a>b` returns `true` or `false` whereas a number is expected

Answer (score 21):

The shortest is probably:

```
 arr.sort((a, b) => ((typeof b === "number") - (typeof a === "number")) || (a > b ? 1 : -1));
```

Comment: It doesn't sort the string numbers though. Should it?

Comment: @nikxda it actually should

Comment: Having this array: `["a", "5", "1", "-1", 17, "abc", 23, -5, 0, "17"]` sorts the `"17"` before the `"5"`.

Comment: @NikxDa well it sorts them lexicographically, not sure if that is wanted

Comment: So this is not a 'try', yeah?

Comment: @volodymyr this question is basically a "how to sort this?", I think I answered that. The other question asks basically "Why doesnt this work?" and you answered with "try."

Comment: This question is basically answered by you and other by me. The only difference I see. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 11):

You can sort the numbers first and then the non-numbers by using `.filter()` to separate both data-types.

See working example below (read code comments for explanation):

```js
const arr = [9, 5, '2', 'ab', '3', -1];

const nums = arr.filter(n => typeof n == "number").sort((a, b) => a - b); // If the data type of a given element is a number store it in this array (and then sort numerically)
const non_nums = arr.filter(x => typeof x != "number").sort(); // Store everything that is not a number in an array (and then sort lexicographically)

const res = [...nums, ...non_nums]; // combine the two arrays
console.log(res); // [-1, 5, 9, "2", "3", "ab"]
```

Comment: performance here is bad. Jonas's solution wraps it up with a single sort.

Comment: On the contrary, performance is better. This is called [_divide and conquer_](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960118.html). Since sorting is usually O(n.log(n)), making 2 sorts of cardinal n is better than making one sort of cardinal 2n. Anyway, arguing about performance for sorting a few items is pointless.

Comment: @Jony-Y disagree. If `nums.includes(x)` would be replaced with `typeof x === "string"` it would be significantly faster (but it takes more memory) [in theory, performance in JS is always a non-deterministic thing]

Comment: @JonasWilms To have the same effect, it should be `!== "number"`.

Comment: not sure you're correct here, you have to pay O(n) then O(mlogm) then O(n*m) then O(plogp) where as in the other solution you have to pay nlogn

Comment: Jonas, that will improve performance siginicantely cantely but since you still at the end have to sort the entire array, I still think that in total a single run is the quickest. I need to do the actual math to check the results

Comment: @JonasWilms ah, yes. Thanks for pointing that out. Updated my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```js
const arr = [9, 5, '2', 'ab', '3', 'AB', -1];
const sortedArr = arr.sort((a, b) => {
    if (typeof a === 'number' && typeof b === 'number') {
        return a - b;
    } else if (typeof a === 'number') {
        return -1;
    } else if (typeof b === 'number') {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return a > b ? 1 : -1;
    }
});

console.log(sortedArr);
```

This uses the [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) optional function to sort elements in one array. It must return a number. If the number > 0, b goes first. If the number < 0, a goes first. If it's 0, their position remains unchanged.

Comment: Explanation added with a link to MDN.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are!

```js
const arr = [9,5,'2','ab','3',-1 ]

const numbers = arr.filter(i => typeof i === 'number');
const numerics = arr.filter(i => typeof i === 'string' && !isNaN(i));
const strings = arr.filter(i => typeof i === 'string' && isNaN(i));

numbers.sort();
numerics.sort();
strings.sort()

const result = [].concat(numbers, numerics, strings)

console.log(result)
```

My strategy was to first find all the three chunks (numbers, numerics and strings), then just concatting them.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```js
var arr = [9, 5, '2', 'ab', '3', -1];
var number = [];
var strInt = [];
var char = [];
arr.forEach(a => {
  if (typeof a === "number") {
    number.push(a);
  } else if (typeof a === "string" && /\d/.test(a)) {
    strInt.push(a);
  } else {
    char.push(a);
  }
});
arr = number.concat(strInt.concat(char));
console.log(arr);
```

What this does is makes three arrays, one for numbers, one for strings containing numbers, and one for strings. It sorts each element into the appropriate array, then finally concatenates them all together in the correct order.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to take this a little bit further and avoid looping array multiple times for decreased complexity and therefore increased performance.

You could do a custom sort function where you calculate string values based on each character `charCode` value and sum them up and other hand handle numbers as they are.

In this code example I then made string values in power of 5, that we can assure string values are larger than numeric values. This could be tweaked based on use case and which kind of data are you handling.

> Downside of this approach is that performance is impacted based on how long strings are you handling so be aware of that as well.

```js
var arr = [90000, 5, '2', 'ab', 'aa', '3', -1] // to be sorted
arr.sort((a,b) => {
  if(typeof a === 'string') {
    let temp = 0
    for (let s of a) temp += s.charCodeAt(0)
    a = Math.pow(temp, 5)
  }
  if(typeof b === 'string') {
    let temp = 0
    for(let s of b) temp += s.charCodeAt(0)
    b = Math.pow(temp, 5)
  }
  return a - b
})

console.log(arr) // [-1, 5, 90000, "2", "3", "aa", "ab"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array .sort() method anyway.

You just need to provide a function to control sorting criteria for every comparsion.

Example:

```
// First of all discretize all kinds of data you want to deal with
function typeClassify(v) {
    return typeof v == "number"
        ? "N"
        : isNaN(v) ? "s" : "n"
        // (Treat all non numeric values as strings)
    ;
};


// Second: implement the sorting function
function sortCriteria(a, b) {
    var mode = typeClassify(a) + typeClassify(b);
    switch (mode) {
        case "NN":
            return a - b;
        case "nn":
            return Number(a) - Number(b);
        case "ss":
            return a == b
                ? 0
                : a > b
                    ? -1 : 1
            ;
        case "Nn":
        case "Ns":
        case "ns":
            return -1;
        case "nN":
        case "sN":
        case "sn":
            return 1;
        default:
            throw "This must never happen";
    };
};

// And finally provide that function as a callback for .sort() method
var arr = [9,5,'2','ab','3',-1 ] // to be sorted
console.log(arr.sort(sortCriteria));

// arr = [-1, 5, 9, "2", "3","ab"] // expected result
// arr = [ -1, 5, 9, '2', '3', 'ab' ] // obtained result
```

Obviously the functionality of `typeClassify()` function can be flattened into `sortCriteria()` to save a function call on every comparsion. I preferred to put it apart for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr=[9,5,'2','ab','3',-1];
    var string_arr=[];
    var number_arr=[];
    var string_number_arr=[];
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {

        if(typeof(arr[i])=='number')
        {
            number_arr.push(arr[i]);

        }
        else if((Number(arr[i]).toString())=="NaN")
        {
            string_number_arr.push(arr[i]);

        }
        else
        {
            string_arr.push(arr[i]);
        }

    }
    string_arr.sort();
    number_arr.sort();
    string_number_arr.sort();
    var arr=number_arr.concat(string_arr,string_number_arr);
    console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

We can utilize the `localeCompare` function inside the `sort` function to sort the array as

```js
var items = [3, 'rob', 'peter', 43, 0, -222];
console.log(items.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.toString().localeCompare(b.toString());
}));
```

Comment: Does not sort number correctly, with: `const items = [3, 'rob', 'peter', 43, 0, 100, 1, -222];` you will get `[ -222, 0, 1, 100, 3, 43, 'peter', 'rob' ]` as result. Sort `100` before `1`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myArray = [9, 5, '2', 'ab', '3', -1]
myArray.sort((a, b) => {
  let aTest = /^\d+$/.test(a);
  let bTest = /^\d+$/.test(b);
  if (aTest && bTest) {
    return parseInt(a) - parseInt(b);
  } else if (aTest) {
    return -1;
  } else if (bTest) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return a > b ? 1 : -1;
  }
})

console.log(myArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit crude, but it should handle the task appropriately

```js
var mixedArray = ["a", "5", "1", "-1", 17, "abc", 23, -5, 0, "17"];

const mixedSort = (arra) => {
  arra.sort();
  return arra.sort((a, b) => {
    if (typeof a === "string" && typeof b === "string") {
      if (Number(a) < Number(b)) return -1;
      return 1;
    }
    if (typeof a === "string") {
      return 1;
    }
    if (typeof b === "string") {
      return -1;
    }
  });
};
console.log(mixedSort(mixedArray));
```