# javascript array sort strings and numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I would like to sort array with strings and numbers.

```
var toSort = ['100', 'Calc', '30', '43', '52', '16', '10', '11', '12', 'Calc', '2', 'N/A', '8'];
```

the expected behavior is when sorting the string will be sorted at the end of the list for both states (asc and desc), like:
asc:

```
['2','8','10','11','12','16','30','43','52','100','Calc','Calc','N/A']
```

desc:

```
['100','52','43','30','16','12','11','10','8','2','Calc','Calc','N/A']
```

I have it for asc state:

```
toSort.sort(function (a,b) {
  if (a === 'Calc') return 1;
  else if (a === 'N/A') return 1;
  else return a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true});
});

console.log(toSort);
```

any ideas for desc state?
tnx

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Adjust the answers from Nick (make the "numbers" actual numbers) in this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53958419/sort-an-array-which-contains-number-and-strings)

Answer (score 2):

You could check if a value [`isFinite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite).

```js
const
    array = ['100', 'Calc', '30', '43', '52', 'Calc', '16', '10', 'N/A', '123', '11', '12', 'Calc', '2', 'N/A', '8'];

array.sort((a, b) => isFinite(b) - isFinite(a) || a - b || a.localeCompare(b));
console.log(...array);

array.sort((a, b) => isFinite(b) - isFinite(a) || b - a || a.localeCompare(b));
console.log(...array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object with 2 properties `numbers`, `strings` with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), after that you can pass that object where you can sort accordingly and return the result.

```
finalResult = result after sorting numbers + result after sorting strings.
```

```js
var toSort = [
  "100",
  "Calc",
  "30",
  "43",
  "52",
  "16",
  "10",
  "11",
  "12",
  "Calc",
  "2",
  "N/A",
  "8",
];

function sort({ strings, numbers }, type) {
  if (type === "asc") {
    return [
      ...numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b),
      ...strings.sort((a, b) => (a > b ? 1 : -1)),
    ];
  } else {
    return [
      ...numbers.sort((a, b) => b - a),
      ...strings.sort((a, b) => (a > b ? -1 : 1)),
    ];
  }
}

const obj = toSort.reduce(
  (acc, curr) => {
    if (/\d+/g.test(curr)) acc.numbers.push(curr);
    else acc.strings.push(curr);
    return acc;
  }, {
    strings: [],
    numbers: []
  }
);

console.log(sort(obj, "asc"));
console.log(sort(obj, "dsc"));
```

Comment: Meh, no need for two different branches in `if`s. Just define a decorator: `const reverse = compareFn => (a, b) => compareFn(b, a)`. So now, `descComparator = reverse(ascComparator)`. This allows for direct elimination of the duplicate code: https://jsbin.com/vizunex/1/edit?js,console

Comment: BTW, `a - b` (or `b - a`) does not actually sort strings, since the result is `NaN`, so there is no well-defined place for it.